# Excel Macro get links redirects

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a macro to check the redirect links from cell A1:A10 ?

For example: on cell A1 I have the link "www.pplware.com" but when we open the link www.pplware.com we are redirect to another site "https://ppware.sapo.pt"

Is it possible to write the redirect link to cells B1:B10 ? 
B1: https://ppware.com.sapo.pt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long the redirect is done using HTTP (301 moved permanently) we can use [WinHttpRequest object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) to test. Note: XMLHTTP is not possible since this will not allow disabling follow redirects.

WinHttpRequest object has an property [Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383998(v=vs.85).aspx) which is a enumeration [WinHttpRequestOption enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx) where the 6. item is `WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects`. This is default setted `True` and so WinHttpRequest will follow the redirect immediately. But we can set it `False` and so get the response header before the redirect is followed. From that we can get the `Location:` which is the `URL` where the redirect goes to.

Example:

[image]

```
Public Function testRedirect(oCell As Range) As String

 testRedirect = "not redirected"

 strURL = oCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address

 WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

 Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
 oWinHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False

 oWinHttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
 oWinHttp.send ""

 If oWinHttp.Status = 301 Then
  strResponseHeaders = oWinHttp.getAllResponseHeaders()
  For Each strResponseHeader In Split(strResponseHeaders, Chr(10))
   If Left(strResponseHeader, 9) = "Location:" Then
    testRedirect = "redirected to " & strResponseHeader
   End If
  Next
 End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Axel Richter... It works fine.
You are the boss ;)

Comment: Why not use `.getResponseHeader("Location")` ?